# Transaction check error while installing maven on Centos7

Tags: centos, yum, maven

I'm trying to install maven on Centos 7:

```
[root@htm-psycho-401 htmpp]# yum install maven
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.reconn.ru
 * epel: fedora-mirror01.rbc.ru
 * epel-debuginfo: fedora-mirror01.rbc.ru
 * extras: mirror.reconn.ru
 * updates: mirror.corbina.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package maven.noarch 0:3.0.5-17.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java >= 1.5 for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: sisu-inject-plexus for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: sisu-inject-bean for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: plexus-utils for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: plexus-sec-dispatcher for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: plexus-interpolation for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: plexus-containers-component-annotations for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: plexus-cipher for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: objectweb-asm for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.aether:aether-util) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.sonatype.aether:aether-api) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(commons-cli:commons-cli) for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: maven-wagon for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: java-devel for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: httpcomponents-core for package: maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch
... too long stuff ...
---> Package tomcat-servlet-3.0-api.noarch 0:7.0.76-8.el7_5 will be installed
---> Package xalan-j2.noarch 0:2.7.1-23.el7 will be installed
---> Package xml-commons-resolver.noarch 0:1.2-15.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package easymock2.noarch 0:2.5.2-12.el7 will be installed
---> Package jboss-jaxrpc-1.1-api.noarch 0:1.0.1-7.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jboss-servlet-3.0-api for package: jboss-jaxrpc-1.1-api-1.0.1-7.el7.noarch
---> Package jboss-transaction-1.1-api.noarch 0:1.0.1-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package qdox.noarch 0:1.12.1-10.el7 will be installed
---> Package regexp.noarch 0:1.5-13.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package jboss-servlet-3.0-api.noarch 0:1.0.1-9.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                Version                                         Repository                      Size
===============================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 maven                                                noarch              3.0.5-17.el7                                    base                           1.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 aether-api                                           noarch              1.13.1-13.el7                                   base                            89 k
 aether-connector-wagon                               noarch              1.13.1-13.el7                                   base                            34 k
 aether-impl                                          noarch              1.13.1-13.el7                                   base                           124 k
 aether-spi                                           noarch              1.13.1-13.el7                                   base                            19 k
 aether-util                                          noarch              1.13.1-13.el7                                   base                           119 k
 aopalliance                                          noarch              1.0-8.el7                                       base                            11 k
 apache-commons-cli                                   noarch              1.2-13.el7                                      base                            50 k
 apache-commons-codec                                 noarch              1.8-7.el7                                       base                           223 k
 apache-commons-io                                    noarch              1:2.4-12.el7                                    base                           189 k
 apache-commons-lang                                  noarch              2.6-15.el7                                      base                           276 k
 apache-commons-logging                               noarch              1.1.2-7.el7                                     base                            78 k
 apache-commons-net                                   noarch              3.2-8.el7.centos                                base                           261 k
 apache-maven                                         noarch              3.5.2-1.el7                                     epel-apache-maven              8.0 M
 atinject                                             noarch              1-13.20100611svn86.el7                          base                            13 k
 avalon-framework                                     noarch              4.3-10.el7                                      base                            88 k
 avalon-logkit                                        noarch              2.1-14.el7                                      base                            87 k
 bcel                                                 noarch              5.2-18.el7                                      base                           469 k
 cal10n                                               noarch              0.7.7-4.el7                                     base                            36 k
 cdi-api                                              noarch              1.0-11.SP4.el7                                  base                            41 k
 cglib                                                noarch              2.2-18.el7                                      base                           255 k
 easymock2                                            noarch              2.5.2-12.el7                                    base                            92 k
 felix-framework                                      noarch              4.2.1-5.el7                                     base                           481 k
 geronimo-annotation                                  noarch              1.0-15.el7                                      base                            23 k
 geronimo-jms                                         noarch              1.1.1-19.el7                                    base                            31 k
 google-guice                                         noarch              3.1.3-9.el7                                     base                           385 k
 guava                                                noarch              13.0-6.el7                                      base                           1.6 M
 hamcrest                                             noarch              1.3-6.el7                                       base                           124 k
 httpcomponents-client                                noarch              4.2.5-5.el7_0                                   base                           425 k
 httpcomponents-core                                  noarch              4.2.4-6.el7                                     base                           466 k
 jakarta-commons-httpclient                           noarch              1:3.1-16.el7_0                                  base                           241 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk                                   x86_64              1:1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6                         updates                        254 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel                             x86_64              1:1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6                         updates                        9.8 M
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless                          x86_64              1:1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6                         updates                         32 M
 javamail                                             noarch              1.4.6-8.el7                                     base                           758 k
 javassist                                            noarch              3.16.1-10.el7                                   base                           627 k
 jboss-ejb-3.1-api                                    noarch              1.0.2-10.el7                                    base                            54 k
 jboss-el-2.2-api                                     noarch              1.0.1-0.7.20120212git2fabd8.el7                 base                            44 k
 jboss-interceptors-1.1-api                           noarch              1.0.2-0.9.20120319git49a904.el7                 base                            27 k
 jboss-jaxrpc-1.1-api                                 noarch              1.0.1-7.el7                                     base                            44 k
 jboss-servlet-3.0-api                                noarch              1.0.1-9.el7                                     base                            82 k
 jboss-transaction-1.1-api                            noarch              1.0.1-8.el7                                     base                            40 k
 jline                                                noarch              1.0-8.el7                                       base                            69 k
 jsch                                                 noarch              0.1.50-5.el7                                    base                           239 k
 jsoup                                                noarch              1.6.1-10.el7                                    base                           263 k
 junit                                                noarch              4.11-8.el7                                      base                           261 k
 jzlib                                                noarch              1.1.1-6.el7                                     base                            72 k
 log4j                                                noarch              1.2.17-16.el7_4                                 base                           444 k
 maven-wagon                                          noarch              2.4-3.el7                                       base                           187 k
 nekohtml                                             noarch              1.9.14-13.el7                                   base                           152 k
 objectweb-asm                                        noarch              3.3.1-9.el7                                     base                           197 k
 plexus-cipher                                        noarch              1.7-5.el7                                       base                            22 k
 plexus-classworlds                                   noarch              2.4.2-8.el7                                     base                            54 k
 plexus-component-api                                 noarch              1.0-0.16.alpha15.el7                            base                            27 k
 plexus-containers-component-annotations              noarch              1.5.5-14.el7                                    base                            11 k
 plexus-containers-container-default                  noarch              1.5.5-14.el7                                    base                           183 k
 plexus-interactivity                                 noarch              1.0-0.14.alpha6.el7                             base                            17 k
 plexus-interpolation                                 noarch              1.15-8.el7                                      base                            57 k
 plexus-sec-dispatcher                                noarch              1.4-13.el7                                      base                            29 k
 plexus-utils                                         noarch              3.0.9-9.el7                                     base                           225 k
 qdox                                                 noarch              1.12.1-10.el7                                   base                           170 k
 regexp                                               noarch              1.5-13.el7                                      base                            47 k
 sisu-inject-bean                                     noarch              2.3.0-11.el7                                    base                           181 k
 sisu-inject-plexus                                   noarch              2.3.0-11.el7                                    base                           179 k
 slf4j                                                noarch              1.7.4-4.el7_4                                   base                           170 k
 tomcat-servlet-3.0-api                               noarch              7.0.76-8.el7_5                                  updates                        211 k
 xalan-j2                                             noarch              2.7.1-23.el7                                    base                           1.9 M
 xbean                                                noarch              3.13-6.el7                                      base                           376 k
 xerces-j2                                            noarch              2.11.0-17.el7_0                                 base                           1.1 M
 xml-commons-apis                                     noarch              1.4.01-16.el7                                   base                           227 k
 xml-commons-resolver                                 noarch              1.2-15.el7                                      base                           108 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+70 Dependent packages)

Total size: 66 M
Installed size: 175 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/java/plexus/plexus-cipher.jar conflicts between attempted installs of plexus-cipher-1.7-5.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar conflicts between attempted installs of plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4-13.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/file.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-wagon-0:2.4-3.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/provider-api.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-wagon-0:2.4-3.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /etc/m2.conf conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /etc/maven/settings.xml conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/bin/mvn conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/bin/mvnDebug conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/bin/mvnyjp conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-artifact.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-compat.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-core.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-embedder.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-model-builder.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-model.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-plugin-api.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-repository-metadata.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-settings-builder.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/share/java/maven/maven-settings.jar conflicts between attempted installs of maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch and apache-maven-0:3.5.2-1.el7.noarch

Error Summary
-------------
```

How can I fix it, is it a bug in distribution?

Comment: You have `epel-apache-maven` listed in your output, which is contributing the conflicting package.  Try doing `yum clean all` .  Also try `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base --enablerepo=updates install ...`.  If you already have `apache-maven` installed then you need to remove it.

Comment: please put as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Unrelated but this message, on centos 7, but not on centos 6 "Transaction check error: file xxx conflicts between attempted installs of yyy" meant "both rpm's declare a certain directory, but it has different permissions between them" fix was make the permissions match (or remove the subdirs already provided by the first package)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your `yum` output it looks like it's trying to install `apache-maven` from the `epel-apache-maven` repository, and this is the package that's conflicting.

This may be the result of stale `yum` data, so you could try `yum clean all`.

You can also try disabling all repo's except for `base` and `updates`

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base --enablerepo=updates install ....
```

If you already have apache-maven installed then you need to remove it.